# Compression / Caching and Request Object not working together ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a slight issue with an ASP.NET application,

I have configured a ViewBag variable to send to my View (using razor) the next page link with querystrings but when enabling this attribute :

```
public class CompressAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute
  {
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
      #region Cache
      HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1));
      HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);
      HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
      HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.VaryByHeaders["Accept-Encoding"] = true;
      #endregion
      #region Compression
      var encodingsAccepted = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(encodingsAccepted)) return;

      encodingsAccepted = encodingsAccepted.ToLowerInvariant();
      var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

      if (encodingsAccepted.Contains("deflate"))
      {
        response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "deflate");
        response.Filter = new DeflateStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
      }
      else if (encodingsAccepted.Contains("gzip"))
      {
        response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
        response.Filter = new GZipStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
      }
      #endregion
    }
  }
```

The site doesn't take care of the following statement entirely :

```
ViewBag.NextPageLink = "/" + culture + "/next/" + pageName + Request.Url.Query;
```

it only produces the link : /culture/next/pageName but the querystring is not included (it's mark as null).

Is anything in my CompressAttribute that can cause that ? Because clearly when disabling it the redirection works.

**EDIT :**

It seems that the cache is in cause. Maybe the server doesn't re-render this link when reloading the page with different query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server returns the same cached page even when the query string has changed.
To tell server to vary the cache per query string, use the [HttpCacheVaryByParams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcachevarybyparams%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Example:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.VaryByParams["*"] = true; //* means all params
```

By the way, you may want to use the OutputCacheAttribute and IIS Compression instead of rolling your own.

Comment: All params means every params set in the url ? Or every key of the querystring ? Because the only thing i need is to reload the querystring :)

Comment: All HTTP Get or Post parameters ASP.NET. You can tell ASP.net to vary only by specific param(s) using this format: Response.Cache.VaryByParams["Category"] = true; //Category param

Comment: I solved my problem some days ago ^^. I used it as an attribute upon my function who create the link. Thanks